# add a value to a field if it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I 'add' data to a field if it doesn't exist?

Let's say I have 4 rows. And a column, say "datafield" looks like this:

```
        datafield
row001: |a|
row002: |b||c|
row003: |b||d|
row004:
```

How would I create a mySQL query, such that it "adds" the value "|b|" if it doesn't exist in the row? (Not 'replacing' the data, but rather 'adding' to it).

So both row001 & row004 would get "|b|" added to them, but row001 would now contain *both* "|a||b|" and row004 would now be "|b|"?

So it would look like this?

```
        datafield
row001: |a||b|
row002: |b||c|
row003: |b||d|
row004: |b|
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
update mytable
set datafield = concat(coalsece(datafield, ''), '|b|')
where datafield is null or datafield not like '%|b|%'
```

This phrases as: if `datafield` is `null` or doesn't contain `'|b|'`, append `'|b|'` to `datafield`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `locate()` function to check if `|b|` existed

```
update tableA
set datafield = concat(coalesce(datafield, ''), '|b|')
where locate('|b|', coalesce(datafield, '')) = 0
```